# Deploying BrowserQuest on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I can deploy my code to Heroku but it seems that the state always crashed. What are the things that i have to configure to get the things set up?

Comment: @ErselAker  I have not touched it a long time. I am sorry. I do not know how to solve this.